# Cannot find symbol en java al comunicarme con otra clase

Tags: java

Estoy comenzando a comunicarme entre 2 clases en el mismo package y me esta ocurriendo este error, el programa trata sobre ingresar cantidad de trabajadores, legajo y salario de cada uno. Informar el monto total de salario a pagar del total de trabajadores. El problema me surge al tratar de imprimir el monto que hay que pagar en total ya que me tira un error de que no existe lo que estoy invocando.

```
package pagosalarios;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SalariosMain {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int cant = 0;
    System.out.println("Ingrese cantidad de trabajadores: ");
    cant = in.nextInt();

    for (int i = 1; i <= cant; i++) {
        System.out.print("Ingrese legajo del trabajador: ");
        int legajo = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Ingrese salario del trabajador: ");
        int salario = in.nextInt();
        Salarios datos = new Salarios(legajo, salario);  
    }
    
    datos.Imprimir(); //En esta linea me tira el error Cannot find Symbol

}

package pagosalarios;
public class Salarios {
private int legajo;
private int salario;
private int sumatoriaSalario = 0;

public Salarios(int legajo, int salario) {
    this.legajo = legajo;
    this.salario = salario;
}
public void CalculoPago() {
    sumatoriaSalario = sumatoriaSalario + salario;
}
public void Imprimir() {
    CalculoPago();
    System.out.println("El total a pagar a los trabajadores es: " + sumatoriaSalario);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te esta tirando ese mensaje ya que creas el objeto salario dentro del `for` y fuera de este no existe. La variable **datos** sólo "existe" dentro del `for`en la iteración **i**, con cada incremento de **i** vas a ir "pisando" la variable **datos**.

De la mano de esto vas a tener otro problema si seguis con esta lógica: con cada iteración del for vas a crear un objeto y lo vas a estar "perdiendo" ya que los objetos que fuiste creando no los estas guardando en ningun lado. Lo que deberías hacer para mitigar esto es tener una lista o un array de objetos `Salarios` y en cada iteración del `for` agregar un nuevo objeto `Salarios` a la colección. De esta manera luego para imprimir la informacion iteras en la coleccion de objetos invocando al metodo imprimir de cada uno.

Comment: Muchas gracias! tenes toda la razón la lógica esta mal